# Return a server name within an object using Get-Service

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, data-manipulation, psobject

I'm trying to introduce some extra health monitoring of our Elasticsearch instances, part of which is seeing whether the Elasticsearch service is running.

Part of this would be to return the Hostname of the servers, then the DisplayName and Status of the Elasticservice and preferably as a PSObject so I can select individual properties as needed.

So I've got an array of servers which I can pull Get-Service info from:

```
$servers = @("server1","server2","server3")
$services = Get-Service Elasticsearch* -ComputerName $servers | Select -property DisplayName, Status
```

This doesn't seem to give me a way forward to include the hostname. So I've tried to loop through the server array instead.

```
$servers = @("server1","server2","server3")
$services = foreach($i in $servers){get-service Elasticsearch* -ComputerName $i | Select $i, DisplayName, Status}
```

This got me a PSObject property called "server1" with no value against it, which I guess I expected but I can't fathom how to declare the property and then add the values in during the loop.

Comment: Replace `Select $i,` with `Select @{Name='Server';Expression={$i}},`

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks Mathias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... but I can't fathom how to declare the property and then add the values in during the loop

There's help for that! The [`about_Calculated_Properties` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) explains exactly how to construct so-called calculated properties.

You need to supply a hashtable with an entry for the `Name` (or `Label`), and one for the `Expression` which is used to calculate the resulting property value:

```
$servers = @("server1","server2","server3")
$services = foreach($i in $servers){
  Get-Service Elasticsearch* -ComputerName $i | Select @{Name='Server';Expression={$i}}, DisplayName, Status
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help topic Mathias! Half of my struggles are not knowing what I don't know.